# How to do product of sum with Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

I would like to have the result by 1 formulas in the cell next to "TOTAL"

Right now I have to:

1. `SUM(QTY1, QYT2, QTY3)*Price` on each row
2. `SUM`

Is there anyway to get the final result with 1 step something like `SUMPRODUCT(PRICE, SUM(QTY1,QTY2,QTY3))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may decompose the formula into

```
SUMPRODUCT(PRICE, QTY1) + SUMPRODUCT(PRICE, QTY2) + SUMPRODUCT(PRICE, QTY3)
```

or use

```
SUMPRODUCT(PRICE, QTY1 + QTY2 + QTY3)
```

directly (`PRICE`, `QTY1`, ... are the names of the regions shown in your example) .

Comment: it worked - thank you very much. I use the SUMPRODUCT(PRICE, QTY1 + QTY2 + QTY3)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe

```
SUMPRODUCT(Price*(QTY1+QTY2+QTY3))
```

Sorry, I cannot try it at the moment.